# How to execute a function on two values of two separate arrays

Tags: python

```
for value in distance_moduli_error_array:
    DM_error = (np.log(10)*(10**((distance_moduli_array/5)+1))*(value*0.2))
    list.append(distance_to_galaxies_parsecs_error, DM_error)
```

`distance_moduli_error_array` and `distance_moduli_array` are two arrays each with 8 values. I'm trying to figure out the best way to execute the calculation stored in the `DM_error` variable on each value in both arrays. My code above doesn't work, because for each value in the `distance_moduli_error_array` array, it's doing the calculation for every value in the `distance_moduli_array` array, whereas I want it to do a 1-1 calculation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for x,y in zip(distance_moduli_error_array, distance_moduli_array):
    DM_error = (np.log(10)*(10**((y/5)+1))*(x*0.2))
    list.append(distance_to_galaxies_parsecs_error, DM_error)
```

Use `zip`

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the two arrays are the same length, you can do something similar to a C style for loop:

```
for i in range(len(distance_moduli_array)):
    # now access the values as distance_moduli_array[i] and distance_moduli_error_array[i]
```

I'm not too sure what exactly you're asking regarding your DM_error, because the wording is vague. However, you can do calculations on both arrays like this.